# MS Bot: Can't add a new custom Q & A

Tags: botframework

Trying out MS Bot QnA Maker.

I was able to load an FAQ from a site.  After running the sandbox bot couldn't find a way to add an answer to a new question.  Where can this be done?

Comment: Do you have access to the KnowledeBase from the QnA Maker site?

Comment: Assuming you mean the KB created from our site content - yes.

Answer (score 0):

As a start point you can use [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleEchoBot) simple sample provided by Microsoft.
There is a [file](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleEchoBot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs) called `MessageController` where all the messages are handled.

To make a simple Q&A just modify this function of that file:

```
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    // check if activity is of type message
    if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

To something like this:

```
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    // check if activity is of type message
    if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        if (activity.Text.ToLower() == "what is your name?")
        {
            var reply = activity.CreateReply("Superbot!");
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }
}
```

And you'll get a bot which answers "Superbot!" to question "What is your name?".

Comment: FYI - This is not related to QnA Maker and the question he asked.